# Shortest way to create JSON in PHP from database fields

Tags: php, json, double-quotes, single-quotes

In PHP, I want to put some database results as JSON into the options of an HTML's select. Each option will be something like

```
<option value='{"id":1,"name":"height","type"=2,"value"=0,"unit"="m"}'>height</option>
```

The PHP code for this is a mess, because JSON requires double quotes, which PHP uses to parse variables inside strings.

```
echo '      <option value=\'{"id":'.$row['id'].',"name":"'.$row['name'].'","type":'.$row['type'].',"value":'.$v.',"unit":"'.$row['unit'].'"}\'>'.$row['name']."</option>\n";
```

If JSON accepted single quotes, instead of double quotes, this would be simpler:

```
echo "      <option value=\"{'id':$row[id],'name':'$row[name]','type':$row[type],'value':$v,'unit':'$row[unit]'}\">$row[name]</option>\n";
```

An alternative would be to write `\"` instead of `'`, but this may be cumbersome.

Is there any easier way to do this?

EDIT

I'm not having issues with escaping, I just want to know the best, shortest way to write this kind of code in PHP.

I'm posting my own answer here, since it seems that sometimes I'm speaking Chinese and people just can't understand:

```
echo "      <option value='".json_encode(['id'=>$row['id'],'name'=>$row['name'],'type'=>$row['type'],'value'=>$v,'unit'=>$row['unit']])."'>$row[name]</option>\n";
```

That's not the shortest, but at least it's clear. It would be shorter if JSON could accept single quotes, but it seems that's not a possibility.

Comment: My advice: find a completely different approach.  How screwed up will your application become when users realise they can manually customize this data?  You need an immutable resource so that when the user selects an option, then that value is used to return all that respective data.  In short, don't park project data in your markup as a short cut.  I cannot answer because there aren't enough details and it would be Too Broad to answer concisely.

Comment: This is an XY Problem.  What are you _actually_ trying to achieve?  Is this inside of a standard form submission or part of an ajax request?

Comment: @mickmackusa I'm trying to avoid Ajax request to avoid another query into the database. Just thought this approach is faster.

Comment: Well, IF it is faster, it is also introducing instability and insecurity into your application.  This needs to be a greater concern for you.

Comment: @mickmackusa All the data is being checked on the server side. There's no use for the user to try to mess with it.

Comment: If the data is checked server-side, then I don't see the point in bloating your `<option>` tag markup.  Again, I don't know what you are ultimately trying to do, but you could write a json object called `let lookup = <?php echo json_encode($yourAssocArray); ?>;` then you can reference it as much as you like in your js scriptings (e.g. `lookup.height`) and don't need to worry about escaping issues.

Comment: If you insist on bloating your markup, your tag can be printed as `echo "<option value="$v" data-id=$row['id'] data-name="$row['name']" data-type="$row['type']" data-unit'="$row['unit']">$row['name']</option>\n";`

Comment: @mickmackusa Yes, this makes it shorter (even shorter if we remove some unnecessary quotes). But some of this data is used inside the same javascript session, part of it is sent via post, so the JSON option seems the way to go (at least by now). Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you write values to a text-format, whether that is HTML, URLS, Sql, etc, you need to think about escaping. You're running into this issue because `"` is appearing, but the fact that this is not on your radar means you *probably* are not doing this for other values, which means that you are likely susceptible of XSS security problems.

In this case the escaping function you want is [`htmlspecialchars`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php).

The way you generate the JSON is *also* wrong and can cause additional issues. You should use `json_encode` to generate your JSON.

Comment: I am afraid the OP's entire approach is flawed from the design stage.

Comment: Your answer's insights can be found in the duplicate.

Comment: Actually I don't have an "issue", or escape problems. Just want to know if there's a shorter way to write the same JSON. The string values in my database don't contain any quotes, and never will, by design.

Comment: Considering this, I don't see any difference between using `json_encode` and manually construct the string (except, probably, a better PHP code, which is exactly what I'm looking for).

Comment: @Rodrigo it's strange you don't see issues because you are currently experiencing them. This is literally what escaping functions solve.

Comment: Even if you think it never appears in your database, it is good practice to always escape for the context in which these strings are used in. Not doing this and denying it's use is a major red flag.

Comment: @Evert I'm asking about the shortest way to use PGSQL_ASSOC database fields with JSON in PHP. That's not an "issue" thing (at least the way I understand this word, being a non-native English speaker). Besides, to show my whole project and database design here is an overkill, so there's no point in discussing that. Right?

Comment: @Rodrigo are you asking for a 'code golf' answer? Or the best, cleanest, most maintainable way. Because if it's the latter, it's using escaping function such as `json_encode`. Which appears to be your 'own answer' too. However, your own answer is still susceptible to XSS issues.

Comment: Yes, I began thinking of "code golf", but now you guys made me think about security. If you have a short answer that avoids XSS issues, I'd be glad to read it.

Comment: @Rodrigo my answer is _exactly that_. Use htmlspecialchars and json_encode.

Comment: htmlspecialchars($row['id']), htmlspecialchars($row['name'])... for each value in the array? Or htmlspecialchars(json_encode(...))?

Comment: The inner format is JSON, the outer format HTML. This means you escape for HTML last, and you should encode the entire JSON string, not just individual values.